# TypeError: Number is not a function - when trying to use Google Maps API V3 DirectionsService

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm pretty embarrassed to ask this as I'm sure it's something super simple that I'm missing.

I've seen several questions just like this on the interwebs but I can't seem to use those answers to fix my issue. I've seen tutorials and code that look very similar to mine but for some reason I'm getting an error, and the stack trace isn't helpful at all.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=name-changed-to-protect-the-innocent">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="directions.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <section id="map"></section>
  </body>
</html>
```

My javascript:

```
function initialize() {

  var map, service;

  // Create the Google Map
  createMap();
  getRoute();


  function createMap() {

    // Set mapOptions
    var mapOptions = {
      center: { lat: 37.388769, lng: -122.158954 },
      zoom: 15
    };

    // Create map with options
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  }

  function getRoute() {
    var orig = { lat: 37.388769, lng: -122.158954 };
    var dest = { lat: 37.391979, lng: -122.167891 };

    var routeOptions = {
      origin: orig,
      destination: dest,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    service.route(routeOptions, handleDirections);
  }

  function handleDirections(result, status) {
    if ( status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK ) {
      console.log("this worked");
    }
    else {
      console.log("this didn't work");
    }
  }

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

My error in the console when loading the page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function   VM2966:64
 KJ                          VM2970:2
 taa                         VM2970:9
 yaa                         VM2970:7
 xaa                         VM2970:10
 (anonymous function)        main.js:26
 Wf                          VM2970:10
 u1.(anonymous function).Sj  main.js:37
 (anonymous function)        main.js:26
 Xf                          VM2970:54
 (anonymous function)        VM2966:31
 vh.util                     main.js:37
 (anonymous function)        main.js:25
 (anonymous function)        main.js:25
 (anonymous function)        main.js:25
 (anonymous function)        main.js:26
 Qf                          main.js:25
 Mf.(anonymous function).D   directions.js:1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that

```
 var orig = { lat: 37.388769, lng: -122.158954 };
 var dest = { lat: 37.391979, lng: -122.167891 };
```

Are not `google.maps.LatLng` objects.

Change thoses lines by this :

```
var orig = new google.maps.LatLng(37.388769, -122.158954);
var dest = new google.maps.LatLng(37.391979, -122.167891);
```

Check out the example below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Directions Exemple</title>

    </head>

<body>

    <div id="map" style="width:500px;height: 500px;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
            function initialize() {

                var map, service;

                // Create the Google Map
                createMap();
                getRoute();


                function createMap() {

                    // Set mapOptions
                    var mapOptions = {
                        center: { lat: 37.388769, lng: -122.158954 },
                        zoom: 15
                    };

                    // Create map with options
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
                }

                function getRoute() {
                    var orig = new google.maps.LatLng(37.388769, -122.158954);
                    var dest = new google.maps.LatLng(37.391979, -122.167891);

                    var routeOptions = {
                        origin: orig,
                        destination: dest,
                        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                    };

                    service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

                    service.route(routeOptions, handleDirections);
                }

                function handleDirections(result, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        console.log("this worked");
                    } else {
                        console.log("this didn't work");
                    }
                }

            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Really? I was under the impression (based on this doc https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) that any LatLng object could be substituted with a LatLng literal, which is the hash representation I was using. Is that not correct?

Comment: No, it is not. As you can see the contructor is `LatLng` to which you pass a `latitude` and a `longitude` and an optional `noWrap` boolean value. `LatLng(lat:number, lng:number, noWrap?:boolean)`
the `lat:number` and `lng:number` are just there to indicate what paremeter it takes and in which order

Comment: Well, you were definitely right about that. Works just fine after using the object instead of the literal. My follow up question would be, how am I supposed to know which API's support the object literal vs the LatLng object and secondly, how was I supposed to know from the error message that the LatLng object was the source of the problem?

Comment: Yes I understand the constructor, I was specifically referring to this section of the documentation: ```Object literals are accepted in place of LatLng objects, as a convenience, in many places. These are converted to LatLng objects when the Maps API encounters them.```

Comment: Well, your are right, it seems like for `DirectionsRequest` they missed the implementation because for the center map it worked.
I guess you can pass literals and if it does not work try with LatLng objects.